# Delete MC loaded in runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have loaded a library's `MovieClip` onto the stage with this code:

```
addChildAt(MC_1, 0);
```

In this `MovieClip` I have some `MovieClips` used as buttons. When I press on one of this button it changes color (goto frame2).

After that, I removed `MC_1` from stage like so:

```
removeChildAt(0);
```

and loaded another `MovieClip` similar to the `MC_1` like so:

```
addChildAt(MC_2, 0);
```

The problem is that, if I load another `MC_1`, the last button pressed still remains colored.

How do I unload it completely from the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are not loading *another* `MC_1`, you are adding the same instance that's referenced by `MC_1`. "Loading" a movie clip is not just adding, it's also *instantiating*, to do this, you call `MC_1 = new Something();`. So, in order to add a completely new movie clip that has a prototype in the library, you have to re-instantiate the variable you use by placing `MC_1 = new Something()` where `Something` is the name of the movie clip in the library.

You can also make a different approach: you give the prototype a function that'll react on the `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE` event, which will make all the buttons in the MC to change their states to default. Like this:

```
public class Something extends MovieClip {
    // any other functionality is here
    public function Something() {
        // ...
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,resetMC);
    }
    private function resetMC(e:Event):void {
        button_1.gotoAndStop(1); // make sure to place proper name of buttons
        ... // place one gotoAndStop() call per button you want to switch back
    }
}
```

Then, as soon as you do `removeChild(MC_1)`, this code kicks in, making all of the `MC_1`'s buttons (well, all that are referenced in the `resetMC()` function) to show the corresponding frame (here, `button_1` will show first frame). This approach is generally better, because you don't make a new instance to appear in memory, thus you retain the control of the present `MC_1`.

Comment: Thanks!! i used the second approach!! It works fine ;)